Can anyone tell me what these connectors are?
I found these connector in my Intel NUC and I was wondering what they are for. I thought one is a USB3 header, but it looks nothing like one. I am using the chip on the right is for WiFi.


Looks like a USB 2 and USB 3 connectors. One is absolutely a USB 3 header given the printed label.

Can't quickly find a corroborating photo but Intel calls the blue one a "dual-port usb3.0 header" (note the "key" divider down the center):

Source: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000006933/intel-nuc.html
As @ramhound states in their comment, the white one is a more standard "19-pin" USB3
